# running vue in VPS with 80 port

Tags: vue.js

I am having some problem about running vue app. I can't displays hello world component. Vue's index.html is there. but hello world component is not coming inside the app.js

### UPDATED

I followed these steps so far, I created a project on this path: `/var/www/myapp`

Then I open `port:80` and make virtual for that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp
    <Directory /var/www/myapp>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I go into project folder and did `npm run serve` and `npm run build` too. And vue start to run at localhost like below.

```
 App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: unavailable
```

Then inside package.json I added host and the port in "serve":

```
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve --host my-ip --port 80",
```

But when I run `npm run serve` command. Vue running the project port 81? if I change the port 81. then vue start to run port 82 it's like vue running away :)

So I also create `vue.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        open: process.platform === 'myapp',
        host: 'my-ip',
        port: 80, 
        https: true,
        hotOnly: false,
    },
}
```

But i didn't worked out either. I only see empty page on the screen. and when I use `npm run serve` or `npm run build` it start to run the project `port 81` or else...

Comment: I'm not familiar with vue-cli-service, but it looks like it's serving your app; not Apache. Though you've set up an Apache server. Could it be that Apache is already listening on port 80, so when your Vue app tries to listen on port 80, it's taken, and so chooses the next available port? Try shutting Apache down and starting your vue service again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy a Vue app built with Vue CLI v3 to an Apache server, follow these steps...

1. Build your app for production.

   ```sh
   npm run build
   ```

   Typically, this is done locally in your development environment.
2. Copy the contents of the `dist` folder to your Apache / virtual-host document root.

   In your case this appears to be `/var/www/myapp`. Since you mentioned a VPS, you would need to use some sort of file transfer tool like `rsync` (CLI) or if you're on Windows and prefer a GUI, I recommend [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

   ```sh
   rsync -hrvz --delete dist/ you@your.vps.address:/var/www/myapp/
   ```

---

If you're using Vue Router with [HTML5 History Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), you'll also need to enable URL rewriting by adding this to your `<VirtualHost>` config or to a `.htaccess` file in the document root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

<sub>From https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache</sub>

---

#### Update

If you're intent on hosting source files in your production system and building your app there, the simple solution is to point the virtual-host `DocumentRoot` at the `dist` folder, eg

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/dist
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/dist>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. Before I start anything I want to make something clear. On this path `/var/www/` I created my vue app. and it's `/var/www/myapp`, inside the app `myapp` I run these command `npm install` and `npm run build` okay after the npm run build. it creates the `dist` folder. SO FROM HERE (I am using **transmit** by the way) do you mean taking the contents of the dist folder, outside the dist folder? And then deleting the dist folder, because nothing inside it anymore. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't build the app on your VPS. As I mentioned in my answer, the build part happens on your local development environment but if you're still keen to host source files on your VPS and build it there, I'll update my answer with some instructions

Comment: It worked out, thank you! But actually I want know, why you don't build the app directly on VPS and you choose deploying the app?

Comment: Production systems should have only what they need. Your source code belongs in your version control and build systems, not production.